# Simulating FULL OUTER JOIN: Performance of UNION of LEFT+RIGHT JOIN vs cross join

Tags: sql, ms-access, outer-join, jet

The Access / Jet database engine doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`s:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.JoinField = Table2.JoinField
```

The commonly recommended alternative is to `UNION` the results of the `LEFT` and `RIGH JOIN`s; some variation on the following:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.JoinField = Table2.JoinField

UNION ALL 
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.JoinField = Table2.JoinField
WHERE Table1.JoinField IS NULL
```

However, isn't it also possible to use a cross join?

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.JoinField = Table2.JoinField
    OR Table1.JoinField IS NULL
    OR Table2.JoinField IS NULL
```

Are there any performance penalties or other downsides to using a cross join in this way?

Comment: I recommend creating two tables, filling them with dummy data, and comparing `full join` results to your `,` alternative.

Comment: @hvd I don't feel competent enough to create tables with sufficiently relevant dummy data and structure to conduct such an experiment.

Comment: I didn't think the where clause was necessary in the UNION option... In fact I feel it could stop you getting some of the required results... Am I missing something?

Comment: @IsaacReefman If using a `UNION ALL`, then the `INNER JOIN`ed records would come in twice. One alternative is to use `UNION`, but that assumes there are no other duplicate records.

Comment: I believe all the results are completely different. The last sql will just give you common rows. The 2nd sql and 1st sql will give dirr results too.

Comment: Your cross join isn't a `FULL OUTER JOIN` at all. It's an inner join that also matches `NULL` to all records. In a `CROSS JOIN`, rows from one table are always matched with rows from another table, while in a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, there are rows that are matched to nothing.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth You are quite correct. Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: @Fact What different results will there be between the first and second SQL statements?

Comment: Although you get the same row counts , but the column values will differ.  When you union col1 from table1 to col2 of table2 the resulting output will have combined values into a single column. Whereas in the first query, they are still in different columns.

Comment: @Fact I don't understand. The `UNION` is never combining two different columns into one column; in both cases it's `SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* FROM Table1 <x> JOIN Table2 ON Table1.JoinField = Table2.JoinField`.

Comment: The definition of `full join` is `inner join` rows `union all` unmatched left table rows extended by nulls `union all` right table rows extended by nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cross join isn't a `FULL OUTER JOIN` at all. It's an inner join that also matches NULL to all records.

In a `CROSS JOIN`, rows from one table are always matched with rows from another table, while in a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, there are rows that are matched to nothing.

To illustrate, I created a small [sample](http://rextester.com/GZIN52041) (T-SQL, but that's not relevant). You can see that an inequal row is returned.

You can, however, use a `CROSS JOIN` to emulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, if there are no `Null` values, by appending a `Null` row, using `NOT EXISTS`, and some more tricks. You'll see, however, that this is a very elaborate solution, and the normal `UNION` is usually preferred:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM #Table1 UNION ALL SELECT Null, Null) t1, (SELECT * FROM #Table2 UNION ALL SELECT Null, Null) t2
WHERE (t1.JoinField = t2.JoinField
OR (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Table2 WHERE #Table2.JoinField = t1.JoinField) AND t1.JoinField Is Not Null AND t2.JoinField IS NULL)
OR (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Table1 WHERE #Table1.JoinField = t2.JoinField) AND t2.JoinField Is Not Null AND t1.JoinField IS NULL))
AND (t1.JoinField Is Not Null Or t2.JoinField Is Not Null)
```

(In the linked sample, you can see it in action)

Answer (score 0):

As I am using Redshift there may be syntax difference.

```
With a as
(
Select 1 id union all
Select 2 union all
Select 3 
)
, b as 
(
Select 2 d union all
Select 4 union all
Select 5 
)
Select a.*,b.* 
From a full join b on id=d
```

Output is

```
id  d
1   NULL
2   2
3   NULL
NULL    4
NULL    5
```

If you run

```
Select a.*,b.* 
from a 
left join b on id=d 
union all
Select  a.*,b.* 
from b 
left join a on d=id
```

You get

```
id  d
1   NULL
2   2
3   NULL
2   2
NULL    4
NULL    5
```

But if you union only you get same result.

Comment: Or use a 'WHERE' clause to explicitly exclude `INNER JOIN` records from the second subquery of the `UNION ALL`, [as in my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286198/simulating-full-outer-join-performance-of-union-of-leftright-join-vs-cross-joi/50287116#comment87588565_50286198). Also, using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` assumes there are no other duplicate results.